# Create Subfolder in NSDocumentDirectory 

Tags: objective-c, directory, nsdocument

I just wanted to know if it's possible to create a subfolder in the NSDocumentDirectory and write data into that created folder, like:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);    
NSString *dirPath =[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestFolder"];  
NSString *filePath =[dirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testimage.jpg"];  
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Thanks in advance for your support!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `writeToFile` might fail because the directory does not exist. If it does fail, you could try the `NSFileManager` class that has a [createDirectoryAtPath:attributes:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath:attributes:) method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right, i had to create the TestFolder with the NSFileManager first. Now it works!

Answer (score 5):

The [createDirectoryAtPath:attributes:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath%3Aattributes%3A) method has been deprecated.

Use [createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:) instead.