# Inserting NSData into SQLite on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, binary, image-manipulation, nsdata

So far I've managed to create this method for inserting into a SQLite database on the iPhone:

```
- (void) insertToDB :(NSString *)Identifier :(NSString *)Name
{
    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *sql1 = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('";
        const char *sql2 = [Identifier cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
        char *sql3 = "', '";
        const char *sql4 = [Name cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
        char *sql5 = "')";

        char *sqlStatement[255];
        strcpy(sqlStatement, sql1);
        strcat(sqlStatement, sql2);
        strcat(sqlStatement, sql3);
        strcat(sqlStatement, sql4);
        strcat(sqlStatement, sql5);

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatment);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Now I'm looking at storing an image in the database. So far I've [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643682/reading-and-writing-images-to-an-sqlite-db-for-iphone-use):

```
UIImage *cachedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
NSData *dataForImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cachedImage);
```

But i'm having trouble trying to insert this NSData into the char array which makes the sqlStatement. Anyone got an idea how to do this?

(I have a field in the database of type blob for this).

Thanks

Comment: Do *not* put BLOBs in the database.  It is horribly inefficient on all levels.  Store a path in the database and put the BLOB in the filesystem.

Comment: I would *highly* recommend using the Flying Meat database wrapper, which has solved all of these problems for you already and is *much* simpler to use: http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use `sqlite3_stmt` instead of a string.  Then, you could use `sqlite3_bind_blob` to bind the blob to the prepared statement.

```
sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement;     
char *sql = "INSERT INTO table (blobcolumn, column2, column3) VALUES (? , ?, ?)" ;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
          {
              //handle error
          } 

sqlite3_bind_blob(insert_statement, 1, [dataForImage bytes], [dataForImage length], NULL);
```

But, really, it would be best for performance to store the image on disk and the path in the database.

Another way to do it, one that I use to send image data in XML, is to base 64 encode the data.  I have it here as a category on NSString:

```
static char base64EncodingTable[64] = {
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'
};

@implementation NSString (NSStringCategories)

+ (NSString *) base64StringFromData: (NSData *)data length: (int)length {
    unsigned long ixtext, lentext;
    long ctremaining;
    unsigned char input[3], output[4];
    short i, charsonline = 0, ctcopy;
    const unsigned char *raw;
    NSMutableString *result;

    lentext = [data length]; 
    if (lentext < 1)
        return @"";
    result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: lentext];
    raw = [data bytes];
    ixtext = 0; 

    while (true) {
        ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;
        if (ctremaining <= 0) 
            break;        
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
            unsigned long ix = ixtext + i;
            if (ix < lentext)
                input[i] = raw[ix];
            else
                input[i] = 0;
        }
        output[0] = (input[0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
        output[1] = ((input[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((input[1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
        output[2] = ((input[1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((input[2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
        output[3] = input[2] & 0x3F;
        ctcopy = 4;
        switch (ctremaining) {
            case 1: 
                ctcopy = 2; 
                break;
            case 2: 
                ctcopy = 3; 
                break;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++)
        [result appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c",             base64EncodingTable[output[i]]]];

    for (i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++)
        [result appendString: @"="];

    ixtext += 3;
    charsonline += 4;

    if ((length > 0) && (charsonline >= length))
        charsonline = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 for sqlite3_stmt and for saving the file to disk instead of in the database

Comment: Thanks, I won't be able to try that until Monday but I will report back. Regarding saving to disk, this is what I've been doing in the past but I'm now streaming and saving the images. I didn't think you could save an image to disk in code?

Comment: Oh, sure you can.  You have the NSData: `[dataForImage writeToFile: path atomically:YES];`  Build a unique filename for your image and save it in the documents directory.  Then save that path in the database.  For anything over 100 kb or so, it's much better than storing the BLOB in sqlite.

Comment: Ah ok, I will have to have a play with that then. Where would you write it too? Can you allocate a area for downloaded images that doesn't get removed when an update is installed?

Comment: Yes, the Documents directory is what you need (NSDocumentDirectory).  See this question if you want to create subfolders there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094376/create-subfolder-in-nsdocumentdirectory.  For temporary files, use NSCachesDirectory.

Comment: Be careful storing downloaded files in the Documents directory.  The new Apple Data Storage Guidelines prohibit storing files in that directory unless they are explicitly created by the user.  Everything else is supposed to be stored in the Caches directory.