# Retrieving UIImage in byte form from NSArray - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage, nsarray

I have an array which contains a set of UIImage in byte forms. --My partner saved the UIImage in the database, and he created an array to retrieve the data-- I created this to retrieve the data from the array:

```
for (NSDictionary *row in arr){
NSData *imgData = [row objectForKey:@"ImageFile"];
```

When I put it in the NSLog, it gave the right data. However when I try to display the image using this:

```
UIImage *imgDis = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

It is giving me an error saying [__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance..

I honestly don't know what to do, so if anyone can help me it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: imgData seems to be a string, makes sure its not NSString, post whats the result of NSLog(imgData);

Comment: Well that's what I thought. The NSLog showed a whole bunch of bytes that will be too much if I post everything here. But here is a part of it: <89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 00000264 00000318 08060000 006586fb b2000040 00494441 547801ed dd09bc75 d77c3ffe 2c63cc43 4bccd2a8 9998a750 2235a555 636ba66a 28d1fab7 e1f76bd5 ...

Comment: which line recives the error?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith The one above. UIImage *imgDis = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

Comment: NSData *imgData = [row objectForKey:@"ImageFile"];?

Comment: Well when I put the imgData in the NSLog, it shows the right byte codes for the UIImage. But, when I use imgData with [UIImage imageWithData:imgData], it will give me the error above. I tried using other images (images that are not saved in database). I converted them using UIImagePNGRepresentation, and I successfully displayed them using imageWithData. So I think the error is in NSData *imgData = [row objectForKey:@"ImageFile"];. I just don't know what exactly should I do about it.

Comment: Have you checked,if your data is retained or not?
It may happen,if your data gets null.

Comment: @iApple do you mean if imgData is retained or not?

Comment: Yes,the data that you showed above,and also check that whats the datatype used to store the data,it is probably creating the problem.
and if you getting response as string,use 
`NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: code for how img is converted into byte form?

Comment: I tried `NSData *data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` and it didn't get an error but it didn't display the image as well. When I put it in NSLog, it gave a different coding. It probably encoded the UIImage byte codes into a different one.

I checked the imgData, it is retained.

Comment: @Safecase my partner said he used `NSData *imgToData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(fileImageView.image);` to store into sqlite. He also said he used BLOB in the sqlite.

Comment: Best way is to write images in document directory with Images_1.png , Images_2.png, Images_3.png etc and add filename to database. So it is very easy to retrieve with path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319791/inserting-nsdata-into-sqlite-on-the-iphone Now bas64 encode can used to retrieve data by decoding

Comment: your data has not been inserted correctly so start thinking to insert at same time how to retrieve it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12784/discussion-between-user1412469-and-safecase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what @Safecase said in the comments, I decided to save the image path instead of the image itself. This way, I could just use `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath` to display the image. Thanks for the help!