# How to store and retrieve NSData picture in SQLite?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, nsdata

I am trying to figure out how to save and load `NSData` (happens to be `UIImages`) into SQLite.  Should I create the table with TEXT or BLOB columns to store it?  Then, what are some code examples for saving and retrieving?

For example, I have classes that persist using a `.save()` method; in the `.save()` method, it simply performs `sqlite3_exec` on a SQL string to do an `INSERT`.  That's great for basic data types, but `NSData`?  Should I use TEXT and UTF8 to encode/decode?  If so, then here's what I have to save:

```
...
let sqlTEXT = "INSERT INTO mytable (photo) VALUES ('\(picData.base64EncodedStringithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength))')"
if (sqlite3_exec(db, sqlText, nil, nil, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    // fine
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

And, to read:

```
...
let picEncoding = String(sqlite3_column_text(fromRecord, 0))
let picData = NSData(base64EncodedString: pic, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```

Does that seem right?

Comment: Neither. Write the file to the filesystem and store the filename in the database.

Comment: That isn't ideal.  For example, I have an app where the user takes a photo, and I want the photo included with other metadata in a record, and that record replicated with a cloud store.  Having external file storage is quite clunky; it's better to store the photo as NSData.

Comment: Then use a blob to store the data. Using text and the base64 encoding will make it take up a lot more space.

Comment: Sweet, that's the advice I'm looking for.  Do you have a quick code example how I would do that?  Thanks so much for answering.

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3320375/3411787